# How to allow contravariant parameters in method of a subclass in python?

Tags: python, python-typing, contravariance

I am using the following code to chain multiple actions dynamically.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union, Any


class Pipeline(ABC):
    def __init__(self, *actions: "Action"):
        self.actions = actions

    def __add__(self, other: "Pipeline") -> "Pipeline":
        new_pipeline = Pipeline()
        new_pipeline.actions = self.actions + other.actions
        return new_pipeline

    def __getitem__(self, index: Union[int, slice]) -> "Pipeline":
        if isinstance(index, int):
            return self.actions[index]
        else:
            new_pipeline = Pipeline()
            new_pipeline.actions = self.actions[index]
            return new_pipeline

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.actions)

    def run(self, pipeline_input: Any = None) -> Any:
        value = pipeline_input
        for action in self.actions:
            value = action.run(value)
        return value


class Action(Pipeline):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)  # note that it's "super().__init__(self)" instead of "super().__init__()"

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, pipeline_input: Any = None) -> Any:
        return


class Add(Action):
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value

    def run(self, pipeline_input: int) -> int:
        return pipeline_input + self.value


class Multiply(Action):
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value

    def run(self, pipeline_input: int) -> int:
        return pipeline_input * self.value
```

I can run the actions like the following

```
action1 = Add(3)
action2 = Multiply(4)

action1.run(2) # result 5
action2.run(5) # result 20

pipeline = action1 + action2

pipeline.run(5) # result 40
pipeline[0].run(3) # result 6
pipeline[0:2].run(5) # result 40
```

The problem is that this structure inherently requires the `run` method of `Action`'s subclasses to allow only specific types as inputs, and therefore raises the following warning for `run`.

```
Method "run" overrides class "Action" in an incompatible manner
  Parameter 2 mismatch: base parameter has default argument value, override parameter does not Pylancereport IncompatibleMethodOverride
```

How would i fix the type hint problem while also preserving the original spirit of the pipeline-action structure?

(The input and output type checking before chaining actions is done outside the python code, and the actions are chained dynamically, by name.)

Comment: What has contravariant parameters got to do with anything? The error is very clear, `def run(self, pipeline_input: Any = None)`, with the `None` default (which occurs on both `Action` and `Pipeline`), is not compatible with `def run(self, pipeline_input: int)`, which doesn't have a default. Why do you need the default `None` there? Do you ever envision calling `run` with no `pipeline_input`?

Comment: @dROOOze That was it.  I guess I need to read the error messages more clearly. Thanks for your help.